# Java code to load data through CSV file into neo4j DB

Tags: java, database, csv, neo4j

I am quite new to neo4j and I would like to know if any java code available to load CSV data. I have a DB on UNIX system and I am trying to connect from windows machine.

Comment: fix punctuation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just execute Cypher with `LOAD CSV` to import your data with the Neo4j Java Driver or `db.execute`.

See https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/